# wp_star_rating() - Adding a 5 star rating system to theme

Tags: functions, include, rating, function-exists

My goal is to add a 5 star rating system to my theme.  I read that there's a function `wp_star_rating` in `wp-admin/includes/template.php` on line 2121, that I've been trying to use for the ratings.  I am using WP 4.0.  Just using `wp_star_rating()` in my theme's content.php alone returns:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_star_rating() in [LOCALHOST URI]\content.php on line 12`

In my theme's content.php, I'm trying to use wp_star_rating().  If I redeclare wp_star_rating() in my theme's functions.php the content works but when I go to my admin panel I get the error (obviously) that I can't redeclare the function.

Besides redeclaring the function I also tried (in my theme's functions.php):

`if( !function_exists('wp_star_rating') ){
    require admin_url() . 'includes/template.php';
}`
I'm aware this doesn't work because it doesn't like the full url.

The only thing I tried that partially worked (displayed on front end but threw error on backend):
`include '/wp-admin/includes/template.php';`

**So the question is:**
How can I use wp_star_rating() in my theme's content.php file?  Or how do I include it in my theme?

I already have everything else enqueI'm sure there's a simple solution I'm missing but after a few days of searching I have not found much help.  I really can't afford spending all of my time on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redefining `wp_star_rating()` for the front end, you should be able to just use the built-in function.

From the [Codex page for `wp_star_rating()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_star_rating):

> In order to use this function on the front end, **your template must include the `wp-admin/includes/template.php` file and enqueue the appropriate dashicons CSS font information.**

(emphasis mine)

A code sample is also provided in the **Notes** section of the Codex page.

**Edit**

If you're getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_star_rating()`  messages, that means that you *have not* included `wp-admin/includes/template.php` in your file. Try adding this snippet somewhere prior to your call to `wp_star_rating()`:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php' );
```

That should allow you to use `wp_star_rating()` in your front-end code.

Comment: Just using `wp_star_rating()` returns: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_star_rating() in [LOCALHOST URI]\content.php on line 12`.  Forgot to mention that, I updated the question.

Comment: Edited my answer to try to fix your `Fatal error`.